# Cordova IOS Native functionality delayed

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I built an app that is working perfectly fine on Android, now I'm starting to port it for iOS and I'm facing a weird problem.

The app works fine but all the native functionality that i'm using ( notifications, Photos, Video Player ) are delayed until i interact in some way with the OS, like pulling down the notification bar.

Im using Cordova 6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me time ago, and was caused by a plugin which was crashing, creates a new instance and don't trigger events until the app was "in background". Try removing all the plugins you can and check if you can aisle the problem.

Comment: I will try! At least i know I'm not alone with this bug :)

Comment: Good luck, its a weird bug and don't show any problems or warnings, it's a difficult one :P

Comment: After disabling the plugin one by one i was unable to find the problem, so i guess is not caused by a plugin...i'm going crazy

Comment: Well, in my case it was caused by a native crash, which creates a new instance of the app. Don't you have any native code which can be crashing?